# Periodic limit cycle near an equilibrium with zero as an eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

After linearization near the equilibrium, I get a system that looks like this:

$$
\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = -A \vec{x} 
$$

where $A$ is a $4$ by $4$ matrix. After some simplification, I found that the matrix $A$ has the following four eigenvalues under certain condition:

$$
\lambda_1 = 2 + a+b\\
\lambda_2 = 2 - (a+b)\\
\lambda_{3,4} = \pm (a-b) i
$$

I ran some simulations and it seems like the system exhibits a periodic limit cycle when $a+b = 2$. However, when $a + b \neq 2$, amplitude either grows or shrinks. Why does having a zero as an eigenvalue cause this behaviour? Is looking at the eigenvalues not enough to understand this?

Comment: Looking at the eigenvalues is surely not enought for nonlinear systems

Comment: The purely complex eigenvalues $\lambda_{3,4}$ are the ones causing the cycle. The two other eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are simply unrelated hence no, there is nothing particular with $a+b=2$.